# git: subtree merge from subtree and pulling updates

Tags: git, merge, subdirectory, subtree

I have two projetcs in two separate git. The second contains a partial fork of the first :

```
projectA/
   +-- .git/
   +-- plugins/
   `-- project/
projectB/
   +-- .git/
   +-- modules/
   `-- fork-project/
```

I managed to get that projectB using (got tips from [here](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-subtree-merge)) :

```
git remote add -f projectA ../projectA
git merge -s ours --no-commit projectA/master
git read-tree --prefix=fork-project/ -u projectA/master:project
```

I got new commits in both projects and yet, I'd like to merge in `projectB/master:fork-project` the new work done in `projectA/master:project`

I just can't re-use `git read-tree -m --prefix=fork-project/ -u HEAD projectA/master:project` (options `-m` and `--prefix=` refuse to coexist) and `-Xsubtree=fork-project/` as merge strategy option (`git merge`) tries to merge-in the whole `projectA/master:*` (*ie* do not take a tree-ish as argument according to `--help`).